# Kops, autoscale policy did not configure the master node correctly?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kops

I have running k8s cluster using kops. the autoscaling policy terminate the master machine and recreated a new one since then every time i try to run kubectl command it returns "The connection to the server refused, did you specify the right host or port". i tried to ssh to the master machine but the did not found any of k8s services so i think the autoscale policy did not configure the master node correctly. so what should i do in this situation ?
update: also i found this log in syslog file:

```
E: Package 'ebtables' has no installation candidate
Jun 25 12:03:33 ip-172-20-35-193 nodeup[7160]: I0625 12:03:33.389286    7160 executor.go:145] No progress made, sleeping before retrying 2 failed task(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

the issue was the kops was unable to install ebtables and conntrack so i installed it manually by :

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
sudo apt-get install -y ebtables --allow-unauthenticated
sudo apt-get install --yes conntrack
```

and everything is running fine now